# How should Tyk and Kubernetes be configured in for internal K8s TLS?

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, tyk

### The problem:

I am configuring a Tyk Gateway and Dashboard based on the [TykTechnologies/tyk-kubernetes](https://github.com/TykTechnologies/tyk-kubernetes) repo:

I now wish to secure both the Gateway and Dashboard K8s services with TLS certificates.

I've purchased a certificate to secure the external URLs (`https://api.example.com` and `https://dashboard.example.com`) as below but the cert is invalid for the internal k8s service endpoints and so the dashboard and gateway can no longer speak internally:

```
$ kubectl logs deployment/tyk-dashboard
...
time="Jan 01 00:00:00" level=error msg="Request failed with error Get https://tyk-dashboard.tyk.svc.cluster.local:443/register/node: x509: certificate is valid for *.example.com, not tyk-dashboard.tyk.svc.cluster.local; retrying in 5s"
```

### What I've done so far:

Modified the `tyk.conf` and `tyk_analytics.conf` to change the listen port and reference the certificates:

```
{
"listen_port": 443,
"notifications_listen_port": 5000,
"tyk_api_config": {
    "Host": "https://tyk-gateway.tyk.svc.cluster.local",
    "Port": "443",
...
"http_server_options": {
    "use_ssl": true,
    "server_name": "api.example.com",
    "min_version": 771,
    "certificates": [
        {
        "domain_name": "*.example.com",
        "cert_file": "/etc/ssl/gateway-tls/tls.crt",
        "key_file": "/etc/ssl/gateway-tls/tls.key"
        }
    ]
},
...
```

I am mounting the certificates in the tyk pods via K8s TLS secrets (and similarly for the dashboard):

```
kubectl create secret tls tyk-gateway --cert=example.com.crt --key=example.com.key
```

And corresponding K8s deployment update:

```
...
ports:
- containerPort: 443
- containerPort: 5000
volumeMounts:
...
    - name: tyk-gateway-tls
    readOnly: true
    mountPath: "/etc/ssl/gateway-tls"
volumes:
...
- name: tyk-gateway-tls
    secret:
    secretName: tyk-gateway
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution I'm considering is to use the `certificates.k8s.io` API to generate a valid certificate for the service's internal DNS name (`tyk-gateway.tyk.svc.cluster.local`) that's signed by the K8s cluster's CA, as outlined in the [Kubernetes documentation here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/).

This certificate could then be added to the `http_server_options` config and bound to the service hostname.

However, that example seems to suggest I need to include the service and pod IPs as SANs in the CSR.  I don't think it would then be valid when the pod is rescheduled with a different IP address.

> Generate a private key and certificate signing request (or CSR) by running the following command:
>
> ```
> cat <<EOF | cfssl genkey - | cfssljson -bare server
> {
> "hosts": [
>     "my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local",
>     "my-pod.my-namespace.pod.cluster.local",
>     "172.168.0.24",
>     "10.0.34.2"
> ],
> "CN": "my-pod.my-namespace.pod.cluster.local",
> "key": {
>     "algo": "ecdsa",
>     "size": 256
> }
> }
> EOF
> ```
>
> Where 172.168.0.24 is the service’s cluster IP, my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local is the service’s DNS name, 10.0.34.2 is the pod’s IP and my-pod.my-namespace.pod.cluster.local is the pod’s DNS name.